# How do I pass a variable from an external script to the main?

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to make a python library and I need to pass the variable `x` to the main document.

`external.py`:

```py
def get_x():
     x = '123'
```

`main.py`:

```py
import external

external.get_x()
print(x)
```

This ofcourse wouldn't work as `x` is not defined in `main.py`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

external.py:

```
def get_x():
     x = '123'
     return x
```

main.py:

```
import external

x=external.get_x()
print(x)
```

Comment: Also, if you are not needing to populate a variable but just use it in another function such as "print", you could just enter "print(external.get_x())".